# Swift persistent cookie storage

Tags: swift, xcode, session, cookies, wkwebview

I am looking to store a cookie in swift between multiple wkwebviews. I would like to be able to log in using a wkwebview and access the same information throughout my app. My first question is how I would check if there is a cookie and if there is one after log in has been completed and the url is a specific value how I would save and access the cookie throughout the app. I would also like to ensure the cookie is still in place upon rebooting the app. Thanks for any responses in advance!

Comment: Using user defaults: https://learnappmaking.com/userdefaults-swift-setting-getting-data-how-to/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To share all new cookies between multiple webviews you can use `WKProcessPool` so just create the single pool for your app and set it to your webviews:

```swift
let ProcessPool = WKProcessPool()
...
let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
configuration.processPool = ProcessPool
webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.bounds, configuration: configuration)
```

If you want to be notified about changes with cookies you should add an observer to `WKWebsiteDataStore` before creating your webviews:

```swift
WKWebsiteDataStore.default().httpCookieStore.add(self)

...

extension AppDelegate : WKHTTPCookieStoreObserver {
    func cookiesDidChange(in cookieStore: WKHTTPCookieStore) {
        cookieStore.getAllCookies { cookies in
            print(cookies)
        }
    }
}
```

By default all cookies from webviews are stored between your app's launches.